# align paragraph new line with padding of upper line

Tags: html, css

I have some bullet points which is coming from database. Before each paragraph I need to show a tick mark. I have put tick mark using `::before` pseudo property.

Based on screen size a paragraph goes into another line. But I want the second line to start from where the first line started, not where from the tick mark started.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chanchal118/jLbcyxLf/2/).

Code:

```css
p::before {
  content: "\2714";
  color: #00839F;
}
p {
  padding-left: 20px
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    this is one paragraph and the text starts in new line aligned with tick mark and some more texts to push it to second line
  </p>
  <p>
    this is another paragraph
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: add  `margin-left: -18;` style to your trick mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `text-indent` on `p` which will work with any `font-size` you may use (for big fonts - eg:`36px`-  you may have to use `margin` in `p::before` to adjust the all content) see snippet below:

#### Snippet

```css
p::before {
  content: "\2714";
  color: #00839F;
}
p {
  padding-left: 20px;
  text-indent: -1em
  /*font-size is 16px by default*/
}
p:first-child {
  font-size: 20px
}
p:last-child {
  font-size: 22px
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    this is one paragraph and the text starts in new line aligned with tick mark and some more texts to push it to second line
  </p>
  <p>
    this is another paragraph
  </p>
  <p>
    this is one paragraph and the text starts in new line aligned with tick mark and some more texts to push it to second line
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: if font size set to `p::before` as `font-size: 30px` then what?

Comment: Your answer is good, you did the right thing but the bugs are there but its minor. thanks for your answer.
    your answer also change if you use `font-size: 30` to `p::before`.    that what i say.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an absolute positioning for the before pseudo element like in the code below

```css
p {
    padding-left: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

p::before {
    content: "\2714";
    color: #00839F;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a new style to fix this problem.

see the output in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frayne_konok/jLbcyxLf/4/)

**Updated Style**

```
p::before {
  content: "\2714";
  color: #00839F;
  margin-left: -18px;
}
```

Comment: now change `font-size` of `p` to 20px or 30px. This solution won't work

Comment: This is just a solution of how the code is now at this stage, if we check it by changing other font size then how be the solution found?

Comment: Just look at my answer

Comment: your answer is good, you did the right thing but the bugs are there but its minor. thanks for your answer.